# Wordpress pages returns 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, woocommerce

I have a wordpress setup with woocommerce, i just need to add custom get variable rewritten from url with this code:

```
add_action('init', 'kids_init_wordpress');
function kids_init_wordpress() {


    // Rewrite urls
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'my_project/(.+?)/([^/]*)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&country=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
    'top'
);

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'my_project/(.+?)/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&country=$matches[2]','top'
    );

}
```

With a custom query var

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($q) {
    $q[] = 'country';
    return $q;
}
```

I also created a custom taxonomy named **country** for the woocommerce post type.
the rewritten URL above works fine, **but for the reason, i don't know all my pages URL are now broken and returns 404 error.**

Someone could help me, please?

UPDATE ====================

So i reproduced the bug from a **new installation wordpress + woocommerce**

1- I created a new custom taxonomy **country** from woocommerce
2- I appended some products to this new taxonomy
3- Flush url from "settings > permalink"
4- Now cart page returns 404 page, not only cart page but all wordpress pages.

This is how i created the taxonomy :

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_taxonomies', 0 );
function create_product_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Regions', 'Régions', 'kids' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Region', 'Région', 'kids' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Chercher une région', 'kids' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Genres', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent région', 'kids' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent région:', 'kids' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Editer une région', 'kids' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Mettre à jour une région', 'kids' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Ajouter une région', 'kids' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nouvelle région', 'kids' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Régions', 'kids' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => true ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'region', array( 'product' ), $args );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'item', 'product' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restoring permalinks from the Wordpress admin panel? Just go to Permalinks options and click save...

Comment: Yes i restored it 100 times, i see that this is a bug from wordpress or woocommerce, as i said above, i created new clean wordpress setup with woocommerce and created new taxonomy (new taxonomy at the level of woocommerce category) for woocommerce and refresh permalinks and this break the cart page